# Do I need to provide a constructor for all possible combinations of input parameters?

Tags: c++, construct

I have to write some code, but I don't know, how to do it in the easiest way.

In my program there are:

```
Class P
Class HP: public P
Class CP: public P
and class M
```

I have to write  M construct with will be able to handle the diffrent combination of input arguments

for example:

```
HP hp("xxx", "yyy");
HP hp_1("xx1", "yy1");
CP cp("www", "aaa");
CP cp_1("ww1", "aa1");

M m(hp, hp1);
M m_1(hp, cp);
M m_2(cp_1, hp_1);
etc...
```

Any idea?
Do I have write construct for each combination?

Comment: _`Class`_ May be start out recognizing that c++ is a case sensitive language. Humor aside, please give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to point out your problem, as is this pseudo code is useless to explain anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as it seems from your question, the classes `HP` and `CP` have a common base class `P`. It totally depends on what `M` actually needs by differentiating `HP` and `CP`. If it's enough for `M` to use `P`'s interface you can probably provide a (single) constructor for `M` using

```
 class M {
 public:
     M(P& a, P& b) {
         // Do whatever you didn't specify in your question
     }
     // Or pointer references if preferred
     M(P* a, P* b) {
         // Do whatever you didn't specify in your question
     }
 };
```

Even if you need to distinguish from `HP` and `CP` you can still use a `dynamic_cast<>` (for both variants mentioned) inside the constructors member initialization list or body.